# Saving multiple email for a login in application

Tags: sql-server

I wanted to save multiple email id for a give user id in my database.Is it a good practise to save it in one row itself with some delimiter like

```
  User       email
    a          a@gmail.com|c@gmail.com|d@gmail.com
    b          a@gmail.com|c@gmail.com|d@gmail.com
```

or in this format :

```
    User       email
    a          a@gmail.com
    b          b@gmail.com      
    b          c@gmail.com
    a          d@gmail.com
```

Please let me know you thoughts about the same

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The second. Always.** The first breaks [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) (specifically the first normal form 1NF) and it a mess to work with and will bring you countless hours of misery and pain. Some databases (like MySQL and Postgresql) have support for handling array type data, but SQL Server doesn't, and even so it's still much better to use a properly normalized design in almost all cases.

Ok, so maybe I'm overly opinionated on this... and maybe this question should be closed as *primarily opinion-based* but I do think that there's a correct opinion supported by facts on this subject.